# New syntax to set readonly property outside constructor

Tags: c#, syntax

I needed to write a quick `POST` request in C# and decided to copy-paste a random piece of code from the internet. Everything worked fine however the syntax is so strange that I did not expect it to compile at all:

```
var request = new HttpRequestMessage
{
    Method = HttpMethod.Post,
    RequestUri = new Uri("https://www.random-api.com/api/random"),
    Headers =   {
        { "Accept-Encoding", "application/gzip" },
        { "Content-Type", "text/plain" },
    },
    Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        { "q", "Lorem ipsum" },
    }),
};
```

The part that I don't understand is:

```
Headers =   {
    { "Accept-Encoding", "application/gzip" },
    { "Content-Type", "text/plain" },
},
```

One of the things that bugs me is the fact that Headers is a readonly property that is being set outside the `HttpRequestMessage`'s constructor and the other thing is the value that is used - `{{"key", "value"}}` much like a `Dictionary<string,string>` that is instantiated with an initial value.

Comment: Note that's translated into `Add` calls on `Headers` so it's not actually going to set `Headers` and it only works because the `HttpRequestMessage` constructor sets `Headers`.

Answer (score 2):

What you see there done with the `Headers` property is called a "collection initializer". As per [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers#collection-initializers):

```
var moreNumbers = new Dictionary<int, string>
{
    {19, "nineteen" },
    {23, "twenty-three" },
    {42, "forty-two" }
};
```

> This initializer example calls ***Add(TKey, TValue)*** to add the three items into the dictionary.

Thus, all that is required for this particular flavor of a collection initializer to work is that the object to be initialized offers an Add(TKey, TValue) method. (The authoritative and more detailed specification can be found in the C# language specification, [§11.7.15.4 Collection initializers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#117154-collection-initializers).)

With respect to your question, the *Headers* property is of type *HttpRequestHeaders*.

So, does *HttpRequestHeaders* have a *Add(string, string)* method required for this collection initializer to work? [Yes, it does](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.headers.httpheaders.add?view=net-6.0#system-net-http-headers-httpheaders-add(system-string-system-string)) (declared by *HttpRequestHeaders*' base class *HttpHeaders*).

Comment: I am aware of this syntax but only in the way you described it. It's also pointed out in my question at the very bottom - `much like a Dictionary<string,string> that is instantiated with an initial value.`. What is strange for me is the fact that it is used away from the instantiation of Headers (which obviously happens in the constructor of HttpRequestMessage). I did not know that it can be used this way (separately).

Answer (score 1):

This is called inline initialization of objects using an object initializer. It's possible because the `HttpRequestMessage` class has a public no-arg constructor and the properties being set have public access modifiers.

You can read more about this technique over at Microsoft's documentation of this feature: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-initialize-objects-by-using-an-object-initializer

Here's the documentation for the `HttpRequestMessage` class: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httprequestmessage?view=net-6.0